# Unknown column error in this COUNT MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Error is

> Unknown column 'num' in 'where' clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, books_bookid
FROM bookgenre_has_books
WHERE num > 10
GROUP BY books_bookid
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Should that be HAVING num > 10, instead?

Comment: You can't use function group in **WHERE** clause

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WHERE` clause cant see aliases,use `HAVING`.

It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: I would add that, anyway, there's no way you can use an aggregate expression in a `where` clause. `Having` is meant to work with aggregate expressions, or with grouped columns.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you should use the HAVING clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, books_bookid
FROM bookgenre_has_books
GROUP BY books_bookid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

The SQL HAVING clause is used in combination with the SQL GROUP BY clause. It can be used in an SQL SELECT statement to filter the records that a SQL GROUP BY returns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) , books_bookid
 FROM bookgenre_has_books
 GROUP BY books_bookid
 having count(*) > 10`
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write like this

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) , books_bookid
   FROM bookgenre_has_books
   GROUP BY books_bookid
   having count(*) > 10
```

you are checking for duplicates more then for that column **books_bookid**